# Centralizar valores de cada bar nos gráficos matplotlib usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Estou fazendo estudos sobre a biblioteca `matplotlib` em linguagem Python extraindo dados de um banco local, utilizando também a bilioteca `sqlite3`, a quantidade de cidades que fazem aniversário em casa mês do ano. Ao criar os labels para cada `bar` do gráfico, notei que eles não ficam alinhados, do jeito correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei utilizar alinhamentos como `va='top'`, `ha='center'`, `ma='center'` mas ao invés de ajeitar só piorava a posição. Abaixo segue uma parte do código:

```py
sql = c.execute("SELECT MES, count(NOME_MUNICIPIO) FROM aniversario_cidades GROUP BY MES;")

dados = list(sql)

mes = []
qtd = []

for i in dados:
    mes.append(i[0])
    qtd.append(i[1])
    
plt.bar(mes, qtd, color='#4B0082')

for i in range(len(mes)):
    plt.text(i, qtd[i], qtd[i])

plt.xticks(mes)
plt.title('Aniversário de Cidades do Brasil por Mês')
plt.xlabel('Meses')
plt.ylabel('Quantidade de Cidades')
plt.show()
```

Para conhecimento dos dados retornados na query, abaixo estão os resultados de `mes` e `qtd`:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`
`[352, 208, 644, 474, 531, 410, 408, 291, 330, 406, 486, 1030]`

Ficarei grato se alguém poder me ajudar a resolver este problema.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `plt.text` tem como argumentos o valor do eixo x, o valor do eixo y e a string a ser utilizada. Neste comando `plt.text(i, qtd[i], qtd[i])` você está dizendo "coloca o texto na posição x=i e y=qtd[i]". Como o loop começa em zero, mas os dados começam de 1, os rótulos ficam deslocados à esquerda no gráfico.

A solução consiste em usar os valores corretos de x e y e fazer um pequeno ajuste para centralizar:

```py
for i in range(len(mes)):
    plt.text(mes[i]-0.4, qtd[i]+15, qtd[i])
```

Retorna
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]